# ssh, sudo, then download?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I got a server A, it has three users on it. I need to download a folder's 70 gigs of content into server B. The server only has 90 gigs of space, so compressing, then transferring isn't an option. In my experience `rsync` is extremely slow 10x slower than other methods.

I have always used

`ssh user@ip "tar zc -C /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server2 ." | tar zx`

This command is amazing because it opens up a pipe and directly downloads everything you want, at maximum speed. It doesn't slow down from tiny files like rsync does. I've used this to transfer stuff in the fast and it's so quick that the 100 mbps upload is the bottleneck.

Anyway but server A has a user I log into, it also has sudo -i, and finally there is also minecraft, the user files are actually under. The user isn't an actual user, it's just the placeholder for the files for security purposes. I can't login into this user.

So what I must do is, ssh from server B into server A, with one command sudo into root, provide root password, and then perform my usual

`ssh user@ip "tar zc -C /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server2 ." | tar zx`

Please help me almighty computer wizards.

Comment: Did you try "scp"? Maybe it is more suitable for what you want.

Comment: oh, i'm not even sure what that is. Can you give me an example of what to type? I use like winscp but i do it to download files through ssh onto my personal computer and that process is usually very slow.

Comment: just tried scp scp: /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server2: Permission denied

Comment: to copy file1 from local machine to remote machine: "scp file1 user@host:path". Inverse : "scp user@host:file1 path"

Comment: but the problem is, the user i scp into, doesn't have access to the file. I have to scp or ssh into the remote machine, then I must sudo into root, only then can I download the file. in our example user, doesn't have access to file1

Comment: couple of things. I think *unix mages of the POSIX guild and conjurers of shell commands* works better. Also, I dont think rsync is the cause of the slowness, as you say its probably the number of files. If you can tar the files, then use rsync to send - it will probably fly like your previous commands. from what  you say server A has 20gig of space left?  did you try tarballing 20gigs  and sending - and repeating that 2 more times?

Comment: so there is no way to sudo with my previous command?
I actually wouldn't mind rsyncing right now, but how do i sudo with it?
I'm having downtime right now sitting on my hands looking for a solution. If I could rsync it, it would take a little longer but at least it would be getting done. Besides the two servers are in the same cabinet. So please just tell me how to rsync sudo

Comment: Did you try `ssh user@ip "sudo tar zc -C /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server2 ." | tar zx` Did it produce an error ? were you not prompted for a password ?

Comment: i tried sudo -i, let me try just sudo

Comment: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `sudo` inside your ssh command. For sudo password prompt, you can pass the password in plain text using the `-S` switch:

```
ssh user@ip "echo mypassword | sudo -S tar zc -C /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server2 ." | tar zx
```

Another method, which I am not elaborating much is using `expect`. You can look into that too.

Comment: it is doing something!@!@

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: YUP! i think it worked! disk usage going up like crazy

Comment: The downside of this method is that it adds your password to your shell's history. Congratulations, everyone who has access to your server can easily read your password. The other answer (the one that suggests `ssh -t`) is much safer.

Comment: @Wouter Verhelst it is possible to put a space in front of any command, so it is not listed in the history. However people who have access to the process list can see the password in your command

Comment: @syss yes, as can anyone who can read over your shoulder. Point is mainly that entering a password on the command line is unsafe, because there are ways of recovering it then. The exact manner in which it is recovered doesn't really matter...

Answer (score 9):

You got the error message `sudo: no tty present` because `ssh` does not automatically allocate a tty device when you are in non-interactive mode. ie you have specified a command to run on the remote system.

You can force ssh to allocate a tty device using the `-t` option.

```
ssh -t user@ip "sudo tar zc -C /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server2 ." | tar zx
```

Comment: haven't tried it, but ey mang, ill still vote you up XD