# Can't send password through ssh command, incorrect password error

Tags: ssh, command-line, password, remote, remote-management

I have a script that does various things, and among those things, it prompts the user for a password, stores it in the `$password` parameter and the executes this command:

`ssh [host] 'cd someDir; echo "$password" | sudo -u nobody -S <command>'`

The problem is that I get the error `Sorry, try again` and then the connection gets killed.

How can I execute a sudo command using ssh? It works if I first connect to the remote host and then run `echo 'password_string' | sudo -u nobody -S <command>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh, sudo, then download?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237121/ssh-sudo-then-download)

Comment: In my case I use the provided answer, but there is an error with the password.

Answer (score 2):

You should try debugging/troubleshooting. 
Change your current ssh command to

```
ssh host 'cd someDir; echo "The password is $password"'
```

You’ll get

```
The password is
```

Now try

```
echo host 'cd someDir; echo "The password is $password"'
```

You’ll get

```
host cd someDir; echo "The password is $password"
```

On your ssh command, you’ve got `$password` surrounded by double quotes,
and surrounded by single quotes around that. 
Well, that turns the double quotes into plain, ordinary characters —
no more syntactically significant than if you’d typed `LDQ` and `RDQ` —
so `$password` is effectively wrapped in single quotes. 
So `$password` gets sent to the remote host,
and not the *value* of `$password` (i.e., the actual password). 
Then the shell on the remote host tries to expand `$password` to a value,
and it gets nothing, because that variable has not been set in that shell.

A command that might work is

```
ssh host 'cd someDir; echo "'"$password"'" | sudo -u nobody -S command'
```

Let’s examine that, adding spaces for illustration/clarity:

```
            … '…; echo "'    "$password"    '" | sudo …'
```

This still has the double quotes inside single quotes. 
But, after specifying the literal double quote (after `echo`),
it *breaks out of the single quotes*,
so variable expansion/replacement can occur on the local command. 
Then we have `$password` in double quotes. 
Then we go back into single quotes for the second literal double quote,
the vertical bar (`|`), and the `sudo` command.

Caveat: I don't currently have access to a host I can ssh into,
so I haven’t completely tested this.